# Match rows in a dataframe by range of values in two columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
SITE_ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
LAT <- c(450799, 450824, 450825, 450825)
LONG <- c(6513879, 6513873, 6513873, 6513874)
YEAR <- c(2006, 2006, 2007, 2008)
data <- data.frame(SITE_ID, LAT, LONG, YEAR)
```

Where a series of sites were sampled each year over a series of years and their UTM coordinates recorded, but the site names are not consistent from year to year. I want to search through the data frame and figure out how many of the sites (rows) are likely the same site from another year, using the criteria that **both** the latitude and longitude for a site should be within 2 UTM units of each other in order to be considered the same site. For example, in the data frame above, Site_ID B, C, and D should all be considered the same site. So for each row, I would then want a new name, for example, a new column that had a corrected Site_ID name (in the example above, sites B, C, D would be renamed site 1 or some such).

I have tried using a for loop where I looked at the difference between both latitude and longitude between 2 rows but had issues with the indexing. I'd like to know how to make this loop check every row against every other row and stop at length(data[,1]).

```
count <- 0
for (i in 1:length(data[,1])) {
  for (j in 1:length(data[,1])) {
    if (abs(data$LAT[i] - data$LAT[i+1]) < 
          2 & abs(data$LONG[i] - data$LONG[i+1]) < 2)
      count <- count + 1
    print(rownames(data[i]))
  }
}
```

I also tried using the sqldf() package but that seems equivalent to subset(). Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I believe `spDists(SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(LONG, LAT), data=data[,c(1,4)], proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84"))) < 2` (use the right zone) will give you an _n_ x _n_ matrix of what's near each other (2UTM or less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
# get the distance matrices for LAT and LONG
d.lat <- as.matrix(dist(data$LAT))
d.long <- as.matrix(dist(data$LONG))

# build the adjacency matrix
m <- d.lat <= 2 & d.long <=2

# obtain the connected components
library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(m)
z <- clusters(g)$membership

# create new id
data$new_id <- ave(as.character(data$SITE_ID),z,FUN=function(s) paste(s,collapse=','))

#   SITE_ID    LAT    LONG YEAR id new_id
# 1       A 450799 6513879 2006  1      A
# 2       B 450824 6513873 2006  2  B,C,D
# 3       C 450825 6513873 2007  2  B,C,D
# 4       D 450825 6513874 2008  2  B,C,D
```